# missing ionic bash commands

Tags: node.js, bash, ionic2

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this, I have an ionic 2 project that I have compiled and run many times using ionic serve and ionic run.

However, the next day after pulling my latest codes from github, I could not run any ionic/npm commands anymore. It will show bash: ionic command not found. I am pulling from a windows environment to OSX.

I do not think this as a possibility but is there any chance that pulling my code base actually messes with anything on my command line?

Cheers

Comment: Have you Ionic snsd cordova installed successfully on the Mac OS system?Did you have any errors running npm install? Kindly run ionic info and show us thee output of your environment?

Comment: @yaboiduke Hi, I am sure I have installed it correctly as I am able to do my development and run the application on my browser and compile into my mobile. It is too weird that the ionic commands are unrecognized out of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why this is happening and my deadline is holding my curiosity back. But for those who have the same issue, search for clean uninstall and reinstall node and nvm.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni Yes for now, however after further digging up, it is an issue with node installation. My npm -g root is not in /usr/local after I restart. A clean installation and proper installation will solve the issue